# How to create a label with multiple styles in it using C# winforms?

Tags: c#, colors, label

When you create a `Label` in WinForms, the `ForeColor` is `ControlText` and the `BackColor` is `Control`, which produce this kind of `Label`:

[image: Normal label]

I want to be able to set a different `ForeColor`, different `BackColor` and different `Font` (bold) to some of the words inside a label. Something like this:

[image: A label with different ForeColors and BackColors in it.]

I googled it but all I have found is answers about changing the entire label style. So how can I accomplish what I described?

If there isn't a simple way to do it using built-in C# stuff, how to approach this?

Comment: I guess you will have to write your own label control...

Comment: The way I see it you have two solutions using existing controls - create separate labels for each component so you can style them how you want or create a readonly RichTextBox that's styled like a label. The third option is as (Mong Zhu says) to create your own label control.

Comment: @ChrisF If you will put that in an answer with an example, I could choose that as accepted...

Comment: @Sipo - not done this sort of thing in WinForms for quite a while now so my answer wouldn't be much more than my comment and therefore not really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd agree with ChrisF that a readonly RichTextBox is best suited for this purpose.
Here's an example of a readonly RichTextBox control that I've used in the past.

```
public class DisabledRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    private const int WmSetfocus = 0x07;
    private const int WmEnable = 0x0A;
    private const int WmSetcursor = 0x20;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (!(m.Msg == WmSetfocus || m.Msg == WmEnable || m.Msg == WmSetcursor))
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

To use the code:

1. Add a new class to your project. Personally I'd add a new `.cs` file called something like `DisabledRichTextBox.cs`. Paste this code in between the `namespace` tag:

   ```
   using whatever;

   namespace YourNamespace 
   { 
       // Code here 
   }
   ```
2. Build your project as normal.
3. You should now have a new control in your toolbox on the left named `DisabledRichTextBox` or whatever you called it.

[image]

4. Add this to your project in the same way you would any other control.
5. Set the `.Rtf` (richtext) property of this new RichTextBox to some appropriate RichText.

Comment: I do not understand the code. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Added a guide to using a custom control. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!